# How can i display jwplayer's closed caption in ASP.NET website

Tags: jwplayer

It is easy to have closed caption when using jwplayer in html. But when i tried to embed jwplayer in my asp.net project, the track tag seems no longer working.
How can i have caption when using jwplayer in asp.net ?

Edit:
To embed jwplayer in my asp.net project, I just copied all lines that i use in my html 5 project, and i think that's why no caption was showing cause track tag seems only work in html 5. The codes are as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myElement"></div>   
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    flashplayer:"jwplayer/player.swf", 
    //playlist:"/jwplayer/playlist.rss",
    width: "480",
    height:"320",
    id:"playerID",
    file: "/jwplayer/uploads/bbc.mp4",   //<%=file%>",
    //image: "/jwplayer/uploads/bbc-logo9.jpg",
    //modes: [{type:'flash',src:'jwplayer/player.swf'},{type:'html5'},{type:'download'}],
    tracks: [{
        file: "/jwplayer/uploads/captions_en.vtt",
        label: "English",
        kind: "captions",
        default: true
    }]
});
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<%--<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</div>'--%>
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click"  />
<br /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
<br /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" id="Label1" text="Response Data" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can i ask for some examples of correctly using jwplayer in ASP.NET with captions enabled ?

Comment: Do you have a link we can look at?

Comment: Hi, Ethan. sorry that I don't have a link yet cause i'm using localhost. I have copied the exact codes form my html 5 project into asp.net project. And the tracks: tag is no longer working. I saw people using different syntax and a swfobject.js in asp.net. Is that the way i should go? If possible, can you give me an example of how to correctly use jwplayer in asp.net with captions enabled?

Comment: I would need to see a link to debug this properly. Adding captions for JW6 is done like this - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28845/adding-video-captions

Comment: So it is actually possible to just use the track tag like in html 5 to have closed caption ? It works both in html 5 and asp.net?

Comment: Could it be a cross domain problem?   I've update my question will full aspx code. Hope it can help in debugging.

Comment: It could be, we have a reference here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28844/crossdomain-file-loading, but since I can't debug anything, hard to say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a .xml file as my caption file instead of a .vtt file. 
I'm running my site in IE and i don't know whether it is a problem with IE. I've solved it many days ago and forgot to update this topic.